# keycloak redirection for different endpoints

Tags: node.js, keycloak, openid

Im setting up keycloak with a nodejs backend my first time and currently im struggling with the redirection of keycloak. For my setup im using keycloak in a docker container, openid-client for my open id connection, passport and express.session. As i already said im working also with a nodejs backend.

So i have different endpoints like "localhost:8000/api/endpoint1" or "localhost:8000/api/endpoint2".
Some of these endpoint should be protected, so only users with specific roles can see them, for test purposes im currently only look if a user is logged in or not.

This is the redirect uri of my created Client in my Keycloak User Interface.
[image]

In my backend i created the client like this:

```
const keycloakClient = new keycloakIssuer.Client({
    client_id: process.env.OPEN_ID_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.OPEN_ID_CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uris: [process.env.OPEN_ID_REDIRECT_URI],
    response_types: ["code"],
  });
```

My process.env.OPEN_ID_REDIRECT_URI looks like this:
OPEN_ID_REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8000/api/"

So i thought this would allow to reach every /api/* endpoint as a logged in user, but thats wrong. Everytime im trying to make a simple GET Request on one of these endpoints as a logged in user it redirects me to "Cannot GET /*" URL: (http://localhost:8000/api/?state=..."), so he appends state and dont let me reach the endpoint.

Im protecting my route like this:
app.use("/api", passport.authenticate("oidc"), endpointRoutes);

So how do i need to configure the redirect uris for a correct endpoint handling?

The problem seems to be in my .env file,

if i change the redirect_uris to "http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint1" it works, but only this endpoint. If im trying to use "http://localhost:8000" it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your keycloak setup in your .env file matches what you provided on Keycloak. Thus set the value of your process.env.OPEN_ID_REDIRECT_URI should be

> http://localhost:8000/api/*

The one you earlier provided will not work because http://localhost:8000/api is not a valid URL if your rule is http://localhost:8000/api/*

The * at the end indicates that any subset endpoint of the /api endpoint should be allowed, not the /api endpoint itself. If that is your intention, then make your Keycloak configuration and .env redirect url be

> http://localhost:8000/*

Happy Keycloaking :)